# Search by product with punctuation

Tags: search, commerce

I'm starting to configure frontend search for user search, and I can't find a product if it has a puctuation sign. For example, a product called

The world today: a new adventure

In search box, if I enter *world today:*, the search doesn't find the product.

Anybody could help me with that?

Comment: 'world:' isn't in the title... so why would you expect it to find it?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected now. In fact, it's "world today:".

Comment: and what happens if you search for 'world today' ?  I don't think I've ever used punctuation in a search, anywhere - out of curiousity why are you expecting or planing on users using punctuation?

Comment: It's a client requirement. The products are books, and there is many book titles that have colons, commas etc. He says that users frequently search titles including that punctuations.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal Core Search is designed to deal with many punctuations, but not all. Take a look at either of these modules:

[Punctuation Preprocessor:](https://www.drupal.org/project/punctuation_preprocessor)

> This module implements a punctuation pre-processor that provides
>   special handling for punctuation characters when they are encountered
>   within word strings during searching and indexing.

[Fuzzy Search:](https://www.drupal.org/project/fuzzysearch)

> This module provides drupal sites with a fuzzy search engine to allow
>   for broader keyword matches including partial or misspelled keywords.

or any of the other core search alternatives - they may pick up the punctuation better.